# I'm all in to <verb> vs. I'm all in ~ing

Tags: prepositions, idioms, expressions

I know there is an idiom 'be in' to describe someone is totally immersed in something, but I've never seen the usage where that 'something' is described along with the idiom 'be in'. For example, is it natural to say like 'I'm all in to hear your story'? Here I used to-infinitive to describe what I'm interested in.

Comment: My instinct suggests me to use gerund.. just saying.

Comment: "immersed" is not quite right. "committed, invested" would be closer to the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase 'all in' originates in poker and other gambling, where it means "I am betting all the money I have".

This has become a metaphor recently to mean "I'm totally committed to something", or "something is the most important thing to me".

When using a verb like your example, you can use either the infinitive (to hear) or the gerund (hearing), often with prepositions like 'on' or 'for'.

> I'm all in to hear your story.
>
> I'm all in for hearing your story.

means

> I'm totally committed to hear your story.
>
> Hearing your story is the most important thing to me right now.

[All in or all-in](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20in) (MW, definition 2)

> - fully committed to or involved in something
>
> *The Diamondbacks are all-in for this year. It's why they brought in J. D. Martinez at the trade deadline. They have a healthy mix of young and veteran players, and they're looking to make a run this October. —Kevin Skiver*
>
> - often used in the phrase go all in
>
> *With my bonus in tow, I got the far-fetched idea I didn't feel like working that type of pace anymore. So I went all in on real estate on my own. —Philip Michael*
>
> NOTE: In poker, to go all in is to bet everything on a hand.